# Why does this compile, but not link?

Tags: c++, linker, virtual

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
    virtual void a();
};

class D : public C
{
public:
    void a() { cout<<"D::a\n"; }
    void b() { cout<<"D::b\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    D a;
    a.b();

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a link error about `undefined reference to 'vtable for C'`. What does this mean and why is it?

I know the problem is obviously that the base class has a non-pure virtual function that is never defined, but why does this bother the linker if I am never calling it? Why is it different then any other function that I declare and don't define, that if I never call it I am fine?
I *am* interested in the nitty-gritty details.

Comment: Compiler dependent, but in this case (gcc?) the compiler seems to generate the vtable as a part of the first virtual method being defined. It can only be generated once, so doing it as a part of generating the first virtual method is as good a way as any to get it done once and only once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most implementations of C++ compilers generate a *vtable* for each class, which is a table of function pointers for the virtual functions. Like any other data item, there can only be one definition of the vtable. Some C++ compilers generate this vtable when compiling the implementation of the *first* declared virtual function within a type (this guarantees that there is only one definition of the vtable). If you fail to provide an implementation for the first virtual function, your compiler does not generate the vtable and the linker complains about the missing vtable with a link error.

As you can see, the precise details of this depends on the implementation of your chosen compiler and linker. Not all toolchains are the same.

Comment: I tried adding another virtual function to `C` and implementing it (outside of the `C` class deceleration). If I understood your answer, that should force the vtable to be created. I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't know which compiler you are using, which is why I was intentionally nonspecific in my answer.

Comment: GCC, but someone else tried it with VS and also got a liking error, though I don't know the exact error they got.

Comment: So when you added another virtual function to C, did you add it *before* or *after* `a()` in the class declaration? Try it the other way around, too.

Comment: After. Does it matter? You answer implied that as long as the vtable exists, it should work.

Comment: Yes, it matters. Try adding your other function *before* `a()`.

Comment: I just tried putting it before, and now the error is `undefined reference to 'C::a()'`. What is going on here?

Comment: Right, so now you've got the vtable for class `C`. However, now the vtable for class `C` contains a reference to `C::a()`, and you haven't provided an implementation for that function.

Comment: But I am not calling it, so why does it need that reference to link?

Comment: The compiler has to generate the full vtable, because it doesn't know whether you might call it from some *other* C++ source file (that the compiler hasn't seen). The linker is rather dumb and just tries to connect references with definitions as specified by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it.

Answer (score 4):

Q: I know the problem is obviously that the base class has a non-pure virtual function that is never defined

A: That's the answer to your question :)

Q: Why is it different then any other function that I declare and don't define, that if I never call it I am fine?

A: Because it's not just a "function".  It's a *virtual class method*.

SUGGESTION:

- Declare three different classes:

  1) a simple method

  2) a virtual method (as your "C" above)

  3) an abstract virtual method ( = 0)
- Generate assembly output (e.g. "-S" for GCC)
- Compare the three cases.  Carefully note if a *constructor" is created :)

Comment: I know this, but why is a virtual class method different in this sense? It seems to me that the linker has everything it needs to link.

Comment: @baruch, the linker needs the vtable, because it is referenced by the constructor. The vtable itself refers to all the methods' definitions, so you have to either define the virtual method or make it pure.

Comment: @jpalecek Is this unlinkable as per the spec, implementation defined by the spec, unmentioned by it, or wrong of the compiler/linker?

Comment: @baruch: it is ill formed as per spec ([basic.def.odr]/2,3: "A
virtual member function is used if it is not pure" and "Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or object that is used ...")

Answer (score 0):

If you want `C` to be a pure virtual base-class, you need to tell the compiler "there will be no implementation of `a()`", you do this by usring `... a() = 0;` to the declaration of the class. The compiler is trying to fing a base-class vtable, but there isn't one!

Answer (score 0):

The need for actual function definition can arise in several circumstances. You already named one of such circumstances: the function has to be defined if you *call* it. However, this is not all. Consider this piece of code

```
void foo();

int main() {
  void (*p)() = &foo;
}
```

This code never calls `foo`. However, if you try to compile it, a typical compiler will complain about missing definition of `foo` at linking stage. So, *taking the address* of a function (even if you never call it) happens to be one of the situations when the function has to be defined.

And this is where the matter of virtual functions come in. Virtual functions are typically implemented through a virtual table: a table that contains pointers to the definitions of the virtual functions. This table is formed and initialized by the compiler in advance, unconditionally, regardless of whether you actually call the functions or not. The compiler will essentially implicitly take the address of each non-pure virtual function in your program and place it into the corresponding table. For this reason, each non-pure virtual function will require a definition even if you never call it.

The exact virtual mechanism is an implementation detail, so you might end up with different specific errors is your situation (like a missing function definition or missing virtual table itself), but the fundamental reason for these error is what I described above.